# Serialize json field based on field name/other fields, without overriding the whole serialization

Tags: java, jackson

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Product {

    private BigDecimal value;
    private String valueFormatted;

}
```

and I want the serialization of valueFormatted havè currency formatting. What I have today, is a custom getter which transforms value to the formatted String.
The problem is, I have a class with loads of value fields, and I don't want to create getters for all (Lombok).

I tried creating a custom serializer, but I have to create the serialization logic for each of the fields, and I need it to behave like this:

fieldName contains "Formatted" -> get value of field without "Formatted" and serialize.

And for any other field, do the default.